# ExUnit - How to pass context to test macros in describe blocks, via named setup functions

Tags: elixir, elixir-mix, ex-unit

Looking at the ExUnit documentation, you can add properties to the `context` struct with the following pattern:

```
defmodule KVTest do
  use ExUnit.Case

  setup do
    {:ok, pid} = KV.start_link
    {:ok, pid: pid}
    # "[pid: pid]" also appears to work...
  end

  test "stores key-value pairs", context do
    assert KV.put(context[:pid], :hello, :world) == :ok
    assert KV.get(context[:pid], :hello) == :world

    # "context.pid" also appears to work...
  end
end
```

But when using `describe` macro blocks, you're encouraged to use the following form to provide setup functions for your tests:

```
defmodule UserManagementTest do
  use ExUnit.Case, async: true

  describe "when user is logged in and is an admin" do
    setup [:log_user_in, :set_type_to_admin]

    test ...
  end

  describe "when user is logged in and is a manager" do
    setup [:log_user_in, :set_type_to_manager]

    test ...
  end

  defp log_user_in(context) do
    # ...
  end
end
```

Which works well, but there's no mention of how to add new properties to the context struct to use in tests, when using the `describe` macro and named setups.

So far, I've tried (quick summary):

```
  ...
  describe "when user is logged in and is a manager" do
    setup [:test]

    test(context) do
       IO.puts("#{ inspect context }") # Comes up as 'nil'
    end
  end

  defp test(context) do
    [test: "HALLO"]
  end
  ...
```

Is it actually possible to manipulate the test suite context when creating setup functions for describe blocks in this way?

Comment: So just returning a map or keyword list from `log_user_in` doesn't work for you? Your attempt also has a syntax error.

Comment: An error? `setup [:test]` you mean? There could well be others...
But yes, so far, I've tried with `{ test: "HALLO" }`, `[ test: "HALLO" ]` and `%{ test: "HALLO"}`. Using a regular `setup` macro is fine.

Comment: Tbh Dogbert, picking out the syntax error in the example I supplied led me to go back through the actual code, and pick out my error. Will accept the answer below despite this fact, as it's correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're doing the setup part correctly. The named setup functions take the context as a parameter and their return is automatically merged into the context. So you actually already have the `:test` key available for your tests.

You just need to grab the context in your tests as a *second* argument, like this:

```elixir
describe "when user is logged in and is a manager" do
  setup [:test]

  test "does the right thing", context do
     IO.inspect(context) # Will not come up as nil
  end
end
```

But, more interestingly, you can use pattern matching to grab the exact keys you want from the context:

```elixir
describe "when user is logged in and is a manager" do
  setup [:test]

  test "does the right thing", %{test: test} do
     IO.inspect(test) # "HALLO"
  end
end
```

Comment: That is right, but it's exceptionally confusing because the question uses the same name for the private function and the context key.